# How to hard code username and password in Secure module Play 1.2.5

Tags: java, security, playframework

Below is the code found on http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.5/secure.

```
package controllers;

public class Security extends Secure.Security {

static boolean authenticate(String username, String password) {

     User user = User.find("byEmail", username).first();
     return user != null && user.password.equals(password);
   }
}
```

I want to hardcode the username and password into the controller itself. So that it accepts only those login credentials.

I'm not sure how to do it, but it must be something like this:

```
package controllers;

public class Security extends Secure.Security {

static boolean authenticate(String username, String password) {

     if (username=="abc@abc.com" && password=="abc123")
     return....
     .......
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track. However, some notes:

- Don't check for `String` equality using the `==` operator. Use `String#equals()` instead.
- When using equals, call the method on the literal `String`. These can never be `null` and help eliminating `NullPointerException`s.
- Hardcoding the password and username as plain strings can be dangerous: they can be read from memory without too much effort.
- Because `username=="abc@abc.com" && password=="abc123"` is a boolean value, you can simply return that result.

Disregarding point 3 about the security issue, your method could look like this:

```
static boolean authenticate(String username, String password) {
    return "abc@abc.com".equals(username) && "abc123".equals(password);
}
```